# I'm trying to extract a string from json using jq but got an error "cannot index string with string "num_objects"

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq, ceph

My json snippet is as follows

```
            {
                "bucket": "sample-bucket",
                "tenant": "",
                "num_objects": 189398,
                "num_shards": 0,
                "objects_per_shard": 189398,
                "fill_status": "OVER 100.000000%"
            }
```

My expected output is sample-bucket and i want to select it using the "num_objects" so i come up with an jq filter below.

```
cat testjql.txt | jq  -r '.bucket | select(.num_objects == '189398')'
```

but got an error like this.

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:8): Cannot index string with string "num_objects"
```

I tried to play it on different ways but no luck on the expected output.

Comment: `.bucket` gives the string `"sample-bucket"`...

Comment: `select` first, then extract. Doing it the other way round moves the context, and you can't access `.num_objects` anymore. Also note that the value of `.num_objects` is a number, so no quotes are needed. `jq -r 'select(.num_objects == 189398).bucket'`

Comment: Thanks @Shawnfor answering. but what i'm trying to do is extract  buckets with num_objects that's equal to 189398.

Comment: The quoting in your example is odd. You have one single quoted string `'.bucket | select(.num_objects == '`, then an unquoted part, `189398`, then another single-quote string. `')'`. The shell, when processing the quotes, hence passes to `jq` the string `.bucket | select(.num_objects == 189398)`. You could have achieved the identical effect easier and more readable by `jq  -r '.bucket | select(.num_objects == 189398)'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This filter first selects the object where the "num_objects" property is equal to 189398, and then extracts the value of the "bucket" property from that object,so this should give you the expected output of "sample-bucket"!

```
cat testjql.txt | jq -r 'select(.num_objects == 189398).bucket'
```

output

```
sample-bucket
```